# Flutter debug compilation error from /root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org packages

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I upgraded to Flutter 2.0 two days back and started to face `Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'` due to some packages.

Then I downgraded but the errors remain. My `pubspec.yaml` looks like below,

```
name: news_app
description: A news app

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.3+11

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.1
  http: ^0.12.0
  webview_flutter:
  flutter_webview_plugin:
  flutter_cache_manager: ^1.1.2
  flutter_widget_from_html_core:
  flutter_widget_from_html:
  flutter_html:
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  page_view_indicators: ^1.3.0
  splashscreen: ^1.2.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  jiffy: ^2.2.0
  dio: ^3.0.8
  dio_http_cache: ^0.2.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3
  connectivity: ^0.4.2
  share: ^0.6.3+3
  sqflite: any
  path_provider:
  timeago: any
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  flutter_tts: ^0.6.0
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
  in_app_update: ^1.1.11
  upgrader: ^0.10.0
  imei_plugin: 1.1.6
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.14
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+1
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: any

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/TBS_logo.jpg"
  android: true
  ios: true

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: sourcePro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf
    - family: serifPro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/SourceSerifPro-Light.otf
    - family: metaSerifPro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/FFMetaSerifPro-Light.ttf
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/logo.jpeg
    - assets/tbs_logo_transparent.png
    - assets/TBS.png
    - assets/TBS_logo.jpg
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

The packages that are causing the errors are `chewie-0.9.10` and `flutter_svg-0.18.1`. But the thing is none of these two packages are in my `pubspec.yaml`. The errors are given below.

```
/root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,

                                                          ^^^^^^        
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {                        
                ^^^^^^^^                                                

/root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:83:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,                                
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                        

../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1449:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Scaffold({                                                      
        ^^^^^^^^                                                        

/root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:276:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider) 
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Everything I tried,

1. Downgraded from flutter 2.0 because everything was fine before upgrading.
2. Tried running `flutter clean` and then run.
3. Tried running `flutter pub cache repair`
4. I deleted the entire `/root/.pub-cache/hosted/` directory and did run `flutter pub get`.
5. Tried running `dart pub upgrade`
6. I even reinstalled flutter entirely.

Nothing worked for me. I tried everything that I found by searching in SO and other places.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems. Turned out that some of my packages where not compatible with flutter 2.0.

I solved the problem by upgrading my packages to the newest version. You can either do it by updating them manually in the pubspec.yaml or by `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`